# How to send email activation link with Heroku and Send Grid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku, sendgrid

**Errors in heroku logs when I try to send email activation link:**

> 2018-01-17T07:37:09.783615+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   [f3c128f0-83ad-4879-ae6c-a54b28030290]   [1m[35m (0.7ms)[0m 
>   [1m[35mBEGIN[0m
>       2018-01-17T07:37:09.891482+00:00 app[web.1]: [f3c128f0-83ad-4879-ae6c-a54b28030290] Completed 500 Internal Server
>   Error in 188ms (ActiveRecord: 10.7ms)
>       2018-01-17T07:37:09.892707+00:00 app[web.1]: [f3c128f0-83ad-4879-ae6c-a54b28030290]
>       2018-01-17T07:37:09.871499+00:00 app[web.1]: [f3c128f0-83ad-4879-ae6c-a54b28030290]   [1m[35m (1.1ms)[0m 
>   [1m[31mROLLBACK[0m
>       2018-01-17T07:37:09.892886+00:00 app[web.1]: [f3c128f0-83ad-4879-ae6c-a54b28030290] NoMethodError (undefined method
>   activation_digest= for #
>       2018-01-17T07:37:09.892887+00:00 app[web.1]: Did you mean?  activation_token=):
>       2018-01-17T07:37:09.892920+00:00 app[web.1]: [f3c128f0-83ad-4879-ae6c-a54b28030290]
>       2018-01-17T07:37:09.892966+00:00 app[web.1]: [f3c128f0-83ad-4879-ae6c-a54b28030290] app/models/user.rb:71:in
>   create_activation_digest
>       2018-01-17T07:37:09.892967+00:00 app[web.1]: [f3c128f0-83ad-4879-ae6c-a54b28030290]
>   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:23:in `create'
>       2018-01-17T07:37:09.892966+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=letsgo228.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=f3c128f0-83ad-4879-ae6c-a54b28030290 fwd="61.6.75.149"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=194ms status=500 bytes=1891
>   protocol=https
>       2018-01-17T07:37:10.572375+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=letsgo228.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=6b2a9847-7844-4ae9-a7df-e1405b86b08f fwd="61.6.75.149"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=112 protocol=https

**User model**

```
 # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
  def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token  = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
  end
end
```

**user_contrller**

```
def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Пожалуйста проверьте свою почту,в течении 1 минуты придет письмо для активации аккаунта"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Comment: Have you any public repository to see your model code or can you post your full model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have an column called `activation_digest` on your user model. `rails g migration add_activation_digest_to_users activation_digest:string:index`

Comment: I have this def change
    add_column :users, :activation_digest, :string
    add_column :users, :activated, :boolean, default: false
    add_column :users, :activated_at, :datetime
  end
end

Comment: Did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate`?